# Get 404 when try open author page

Tags: author, author-template

I am having a problem when I try open url /author I always get 404.

For example if I open url

```
http://example.com/author/author-1 - OK
http://example.com/author/ - 404 why?
```

I try to create page-author.php and resave permalink, but get same result. Also in rewrite rules I see default values

```
    object(WP_Rewrite)#3250 (24) {
  ["permalink_structure"]=>
  string(36) "/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/"
  ["use_trailing_slashes"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["author_base"]=>
  string(6) "author"
  ["search_base"]=>
  string(6) "search"
  ["comments_base"]=>
  string(8) "comments"
  ["pagination_base"]=>
  string(4) "page"
  ["comments_pagination_base"]=>
  string(12) "comment-page"
  ["feed_base"]=>
  string(4) "feed"
  ["front"]=>
  string(1) "/"
  ["root"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["index"]=>
  string(9) "index.php"
  ["matches"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["rules"]=>
  NULL
  ["extra_rules"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
```

What I can do to see my author page ( author page with list of author )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example would be accurate if we were talking about a post type, but authors behave a little differently.  WordPress automatically creates specific author pages (like your `/author-1` example) but does not have a fallback scenario for showing a list of the authors.  (More details on how the template hierarchy works [can be found here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/))

So, you'll need to use a 3rd party plugin to generate an author list, or create your own. You ca create a page template and use the `wp_list_authors()` function ([documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors)) to generate a list of your authors (you can usually adapt your archive template to fit this use case fairly easily).  Check out this [Smashing Mag article](http://Your%20example%20would%20be%20accurate%20if%20we%20were%20talking%20about%20a%20post%20type,%20but%20authors%20behave%20a%20little%20differently.) for a more detailed walk through.

Comment: This is standard author.php page, I don't have post type author. I createa author.php to show author posts and this template work good. But I don't know which template I need use to show all author in one page. I no need code, I only want to know why I can't use /author to show my custom page, like page-author.php If i create this page I always get 404 if try use it.

Comment: Ok thx I find problem in part of rewrite rules, some plugin break it. When I removed all plugins and check in default theme it work fine. Thx!